# Is it possible to stroke a CGImageRef using Core Graphics?

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I have a `CGImageRef` to a shape with a transparent background. Is is possible to stroke the image, like you can stroke a path with `CGContextStrokePath()`? Alternatively, can you convert the image to a path and stroke that?

Comment: are you looking for CGContextDrawImage paired with the correct context state for layering and handling opacity? otherwise, you may need to expand on your question.

Comment: My understanding of the question was that the OP wants to do something like image brushes in Photoshop, where you can take a small image and make it a brush and then paint with it. It essentially just tiles and blends the image over whatever path you draw.

Comment: Basically, I'm taking a transparent png and using it to mask another image. I want to stroke the resulting image, which is where I've hit a brick wall. I suspect I'll just have to draw the image twice -- once filled with the desired stroke colour, then again inset 1px from each edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there's no easy way to do this, so I ended up having to iterate over each pixel (you can get a pointer to the image data using `CGBitmapContextGetData()`) and adjusting the RGB value of every one that was adjacent to an opaque pixel.

Comment: Any chance you could post your code for achieving this somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`CGContextDrawTiledImage`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextDrawTiledImage). It's not exactly what you are looking for, but as far as I know there is no built-in way to do what you want. You can use a combination of well-placed rects and clipping paths to achieve the look you are going for, however.